# Removing partial duplicates from a Union

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 datasets used for billing purposes and I've been asked to provide a report that summarises both. I'm having an issue where the system shows some of the billing in both places, as one side bills on Part No and Sales Order, and the other on Project and Customer, and I'm struggling to remove the duplicate.

The table post union is in the following format

| REF | CUSTOMER | NETT_PRICE | DATE_CREATED | PART_NO | SALESORDER | PROJECT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AC | ABC | 100 | 20/3/23 | 123 | 7001 | PR01 |
| AC | ABC | 150 | 20/3/23 | 123 | 7001 | PR01 |
| AC | ABC | 170 | 20/3/23 | 123 | 7002 | PR02 |
| FP | ABC | 100 | 20/3/23 | - | - | PR01 |
| FP | ABC | 150 | 20/3/23 | - | - | PR01 |
| FP | ABC | 200 | 20/3/23 | - | - | PR02 |

In the case of lines 1&4, and 2&5, they are the same billing as the **NETT_PRICE**, **PROJECT** and **DATE_CREATED** are the same, where **REF** dictates which area the billing came from. Where it's duplicated it has to be the ***AC*** reference that remains, and the order isn't always ***AC*** first.

My attempts at using ROW_NUMBER with OVER have not been successful, as shown below. Any guidance on this would be appreciated, or if ROW_NUMBER is not the way to go.

```
SELECT [REF]
      ,[NETT_PRICE]
      ,[QTY_ENTERED]
      ,[CREATED]
      ,[CUS]
      ,[SALESORDER]
      ,[PART_ONLY]
      ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [NETT_PRICE], [QTY_ENTERED], [CREATED], [CUS], [PART_ONLY]
                            order by [CREATED], [OUR], [REF]
                        )
FROM [UDEF_SALESAREA_SUMMARY_TBL] WHERE ROW_NUMBER() > 1
```

From the above table, the expected output should be:

| REF | CUSTOMER | NETT_PRICE | DATE_CREATED | PART_NO | SALESORDER | PROJECT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AC | ABC | 100 | 20/3/23 | 123 | 7001 | PR01 |
| AC | ABC | 150 | 20/3/23 | 123 | 7001 | PR01 |
| AC | ABC | 170 | 20/3/23 | 123 | 7002 | PR02 |
| FP | ABC | 200 | 20/3/23 | - | - | PR02 |

Where the **FP** duplicates on **NETT_PRICE**, **PROJECT** and **DATE_CREATED** are removed.

Comment: And _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: @ThomA almost, but the amount of entries in a day is not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```sql
select *
from (
    SELECT  *
    , row_number() OVER(partition BY customer, NETT_PRICE, date_created ORDER BY CASE WHEN ref = 'ac' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS sort
    FROM    (
        VALUES  (N'AC', N'ABC', 100, N'20/3/23', 123, 7001, N'PR01')
        ,   (N'AC', N'ABC', 150, N'20/3/23', 123, 7001, N'PR01')
        ,   (N'AC', N'ABC', 170, N'20/3/23', 123, 7002, N'PR02')
        ,   (N'FP', N'ABC', 100, N'20/3/23', NULL, NULL, N'PR01')
        ,   (N'FP', N'ABC', 150, N'20/3/23', NULL, NULL, N'PR01')
        ,   (N'FP', N'ABC', 200, N'20/3/23', NULL,NULL, N'PR02')
    ) t (REF,CUSTOMER,NETT_PRICE,DATE_CREATED,PART_NO,SALESORDER,PROJECT)
) x
where x.sort = 1
```

This "groups" every sales by customer, price and date_created and prioritizes AC ref by doing orderby. You can add more tie-breakers to order by in case there are more than one REFs.

Comment: This looks to do the trick, thank you. I have limited access to the actual data this morning, but seems to look okay on the test data I have.